# I am getting a Cannot modify header information when trying to redirect a user after form submission

Tags: php, html

I am trying to place a header when the user gets a particular response from the API. It works most of the time, but sometimes the header doesn't work and I get the following error:

```
Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /home/ubuntu/workspace/Payment.php:90) in /home/ubuntu/workspace/Payment.php on line 126 Call Stack: 0.0001 238200 1. {main}() /home/ubuntu/workspace/Payment.php:0 2.6037 271848 2. header() /home/ubuntu/workspace/Payment.php:126
```

Line 126 in this case, is the only header I have on the page,

```
header("Location: $ConfirmationPage", false);
```

I am unsure why this is happening (especially since it's not always happening). Do I have a bug somewhere in my code?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<!--
// Cardnumber = "4005550000000001";
// Expiry = "01/19";
// CVV = "124";
-->

<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1.0" />
    <meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no" />
    <title>Payment</title>
    <link href="../static/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="../static/css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <script src="../static/js/jquery.js"></script>
    <script src="../static/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<title>Payment</title>
<div>
    <?php 
        include("nav.php"); 
        require_once ("./CheckoutFunctions.php");
        require_once('./api/securepay.php');
        $ConfirmationPage =  "/Confirmation.php";
    ?>
</div>

<div class="col-md-9 col-xs-8 col-lg-8 col-lg-offset-1">
    <form action="" method="post" class="form-inline" id="form-signin">
        <div class="col-xs-12"><h2>Processing Payment</h2></div>
        <div class="form-group col-xs-12">
            <div class="col-xs-3 col-md-2 form-label"><label>Name on card:</label></div>
            <div class="col-xs-9 col-md-6"><input type="text" name="cardname" class="form-control" placeholder="Name on Card"/></div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group col-xs-12">
            <div class="col-xs-3 col-md-2 form-label"><label>Card Number:</label></div>
            <div class="col-xs-9 col-md-6"><input type="text" name="creditcard" class="form-control" placeholder="Credit Card"/></div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group col-xs-12">
            <div class="col-xs-3 col-md-2 form-label"><label>Expiry Date:</label></div>
            <div class="col-xs-4 col-md-3">
                <select class="form-control" name="ExpMon" title="select a month"> 
                    <option value="01">Jan</option> 
                    <option value="02">Feb</option> 
                    <option value="03">Mar</option>
                    <option value="04">Apr</option> 
                    <option value="05">May</option> 
                    <option value="06">June</option> 
                    <option value="07">July</option> 
                    <option value="08">Aug</option> 
                    <option value="09">Sept</option> 
                    <option value="10">Oct</option> 
                    <option value="11">Nov</option> 
                    <option value="12">Dec</option> 
                </select>
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-4 col-md-3">
                <select name="ExpYear" class="form-control" title="select a year"> 
                    <option value="15">2015</option> 
                    <option value="16">2016</option> 
                    <option value="17">2017</option> 
                    <option value="18">2018</option>
                    <option value="19">2019</option> 
                    <option value="20">2020</option>
                </select>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group col-xs-12">
            <div class="col-xs-3 col-md-2 form-label"><label>CVV: </label></div>
            <div class="col-xs-4 col-md-3"><input type="text" name="CVV" class="input-block-level form-control" placeholder="CVV" /></div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-12">
            <div class="col-xs-offset-2">
                <button class="btn btn-large btn-primary" id="process-btn" type="submit" name="submit">Submit Payment</button>
            </div>
        </div>


        <!--Take the form values on submit and run them through the securepay API. Print the response on the page.-->
        <?php
        if(isset($_POST['submit']))
            {
                $trans = new SecurePay();

                //PLEASE SANITIZE $_POST data. We will be heavily marked down otherwise.
                //THIS will need to put put into a form and posted to the confirmation page.
                //get values from form and set them to variables

                $creditcard = filter_var($_POST['creditcard'], FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT);
                $ExpYear = filter_var($_POST['ExpMon'] . "/". $_POST['ExpYear'], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
                $CVV = filter_var($_POST['CVV'], FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT);


                $trans->cardnumber = $creditcard;
                $trans->expiry = $ExpYear;
                $trans->cvv = $CVV;
                $trans->orderId = "PO123456";
                $trans->amount = str_replace(".","",urlencode("100.00"));

                $responseCode = $trans->processPayment();

                /* If the response code is 00 (success from securePay), send an email and redirect to confirmation page, if not display an error */
                if ($trans->getLastResponseCode() == "00") {
                    //Email information

                    $to      = getEmail($shId);
                    $subject = 'the subject';
                    $message = 'hello';
                    $headers = 'From: webmaster@example.com' . "\r\n" .
                        'Reply-To: webmaster@example.com' . "\r\n" .
                        'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();

                    mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);


                    header("Location: $ConfirmationPage", false);

                    } elseif ($trans->getLastResponseCode() == "") { 
                        echo "<h1> Card details incorrect, please enter correct details.</h1>";
                    } else {
                        echo "<h1>".$trans->getLastResponseCode()."     ".$trans->getLastResponseText()."</h1>";

                    }


            } 
        ?>
        </form>
    </div>
    <div>
        <?php include("sidebar.php"); ?>
    </div>
    <div>
        <?php include("footer.php"); ?>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Your `header` call is after content has been output... content being output interferes with header calls -- header first or it's not a header.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`ob_flush`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ob-flush.php). In the start of the code, use

```
ob_start ();
```

After

```
header("Location: $ConfirmationPage", false);
ob_flush();
```

Answer (score 0):

PHP `header()` will not work if you have any output on page.

**Solutions:**

1) Add `ob_start()` in the beginning of the page.

`ob_start()` will save you output to a buffer and redirection will occur.

2) Use javascript redirection. Javascript redirection will occur even if you have any output on the page.

```
<?php
echo "<script>window.location.href='" . $ConfirmationPage . "';</script>";
?>
```

Comment: Where would I put ob_start()? Right at the top of the page?

Comment: @bandoy123, yes, you should place at the very top of the page.